# How do you join 3 tables in Sequelize that aren't all linked

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 4 tables Properties, Units, Leases, LeaseRates.

| Units | Leases | LeaseRates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| propertyId | unitId | leaseId |

they are all connected with the id of the last one.

I have these relationships setup like this

```
Properties.hasMany(Units);
Units.belongsTo(Properties);

Units.hasMany(Leases);
Leases.belongsTo(Units);

Leases.hasMany(LeaseRates);
LeaseRates.belongsTo(Leases);
```

Is there an easy way in Sequelize for me to query `LeaseRates` via `propertyId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<pre>
await properties.findOne({
       where: { id },
       include: [{
         model: model.Unit, as: 'unit',
         attributes: ['id'],
         include: [{
           model: model.Leases, as: 'leases',
           attribute: ['id'],
           include: [{ model: model.LeaseRates, as: 'leaserates' }]
         }]
       }]
     })
</pre>
```